# Distance between a point and closed set in finite dimensional space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a linear normed space.
I need to prove that $X$ is  finite dimensional normed space if and only if for every non empty closed set $C$ contained  in $X$ and for every $x$ in $X$ the distance $d(x,C)$ is achieved in specific $c$. I know how to prove the direction which assumes $X$ is finite dimensional (use Riesz lemma) but I dont know what to do in the other direction. 
thanks

Comment: In an infinite dimensional space with normed basis $e_1,e_2,..,e_n,..$, I guess, their set $C:=\{e_1,e_2,..,e_n,..\}$ is closed. Probably we can construct a vector $v\in X$ such that $d(v,e_n)$ is strictly decreasing..

Comment: I'm not sure why the set  C you mentioned has to be closed

Comment: @Berci: As each vector in $X$ must be a linear combination of *finitely many* of the basis vectors, $d(v, e_n)$ takes on only finitely many different values.  So in this case $d(v, C)$ should be attained by one of the $e_n$.

Comment: I couldn't construct such a vector ,v, yet

Answer (score 11):

Suppose $X$ infinite dimensional. Then the unit sphere $S$ is not compact (Riesz theorem), and therefore there is a sequence $x = (x_n)_n$ on $S$ without accumulation points.
Denote by $x'$ the new sequence defined by $x_n' = (1 + \frac{1}{n})x_n$.

Since $x'$ and $x$ have the same accumulation points, $x'$ doesn't have any. So the set $C$ of the values of $x'$ is closed.

Now $d(0, C) = 1$, and there is no point in $C$ of norm $1$.