# Distance between a point and a closed set in metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Here is what I am thinking.

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $C$ be a closed subset of $X$.

Fix any point $p$ in $X$.

Then, there exists a point $q$ in $C$ such that $$d(p,q) = \mathrm {distance}(p,C)$$.

I think this statement is true, so I tried to the following proof.

For any natural number $n$, let $a_n$ be a point in $C$ such that $$d(p,a_n) < \mathrm{distance}(p,C)+{1\over n}$$

But,then I am lost as to what to do next.

I want to use the fact that any convergent sequence in $C$ converges to a point in $C$, but I am not sure how to proceed.

Or, is what I am trying to prove even true??

Answer (score 14):

Topology is weird sometimes.

It ends up that the statement you are trying to prove is true in $\Bbb R^n$ (in which we can use the Heine Borel theorem as in [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83505/distance-to-a-closed-set)), but is not true for [bigger normed spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/343950/distance-between-a-point-and-closed-set-in-finite-dimensional-space).

Note, however, that as long as bounded and closed sets are compact, this statement holds.

**Another counterexample:** we can consider the metric space given by $X = (0,1) \cup \{2\}$ under the $|\cdot|$ topology.  Note that the set $C =(0,1)$ is closed in $X$, but there is no point in $C$ whose distance from $p = 2$ is $1$.